# How easy is to find my public SO profile from my Teams profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams, privacy

Assuming I don't use the same username, avatar or the like in my public SO profile, how easy (or difficult) is for a Teams hexagon administrator or a fellow team user find my public SO profile?

The answer does not necessarily need to be "can or can't". If they can access it, how easily it can be done? (e.g. click on your profile and click on "network profiles" and that's it; or they have to look for your user number or something like that).

If it's easily accessible, is it possible to "unlink" your profiles, so that your public profile is not easily findable from your teams profile? Would like to know before I invite my boss to our growing documentation. They are generally cool about time spent on SO, but you never know. You can always get a new boss...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone is in the same team as you they can visit your profile and switch between Public Q&A and your team profile.

[image]

You can see this yourself if you visit [your own profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10844537/poirot) or that of anyone else in your team. You don't need to be an admin of a team to be able to do this.

If they aren't in the same team then the option is not displayed on your public profile i.e. only people in your team can see you're in a team at all.

You can't unlink but you could always use a completely separate account for your team. You'd have to remember to log in separately or use a different browser for the team to the Public Q&A.